# How does Ashley keep systems up-to-date with its entities?

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-system, ashley, scala

I am currently trying out Ashley and overall learning how an ECS works internally. What I currently don't understand is how Ashley in particular keeps its systems up-to-date by adding or removing entities based on the specified Family. See the following code:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val engine = new Engine()

    engine.addSystem(new EntitySystem() {
      var entities: ImmutableArray[Entity] = _

      override def addedToEngine(engine: Engine) = {
        entities = engine.getEntitiesFor(Family.all(classOf[MyComponent]).get())
        println("updated entities")
      }

      override def update(deltaTime: Float) = {
        println(entities.size())
      }
    })

    engine.update(0F)
    engine.addEntity(produce())
    engine.update(0F)
    engine.addEntity(produce())
    engine.update(0F)
    engine.addEntity(produce())
  }

  def produce() = {
    val entity = new Entity()
    entity.add(new MyComponent)
    entity
  }

  final class MyComponent extends Component
```

Which regurgitates the following output:

```
updated entities
0
1
2
```

The `entities` object is an immutable wrapper around LibGDX's `Array` collection. The wrapped mutable variant isn't exposed either to the outside. There is no way this array can be mutated. The overrided `addedToEngine` method is only called when the `EntitySystem` was added to the `Engine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no way this array can be mutated.

Wrong. If you look at the source code of `ImmutableArray` you can see that one of the constructors takes an `Array` as a parameter and stores it as a variable:

```
private final Array<T> array;

public ImmutableArray (Array<T> array) {
    this.array = array;
}
```

The `Engine` object simply keeps a reference to this internal array and edits it whenever it updates the systems:

```
// In "FamilyManager" - called when you call getEntitiesFor(Family)
private ImmutableArray<Entity> registerFamily(Family family) {
    ImmutableArray<Entity> entitiesInFamily = immutableFamilies.get(family);

    if (entitiesInFamily == null) {
        Array<Entity> familyEntities = new Array<Entity>(false, 16);
        entitiesInFamily = new ImmutableArray<Entity>(familyEntities);
        families.put(family, familyEntities); // <-- Store mutable array
        immutableFamilies.put(family, entitiesInFamily); // <-- Store immutable array

        // some other unrelated stuff
    }

    return entitiesInFamily; // <-- Returns the immutable array
}
```

Then whenever an entity is added it simply does something like this (pseudo):

```
private void entityAdded(Entity entity) {
    for(Family family : getMatchingFamilies(entity)) {
        Array<Entity> entities = families.get(family);
        entities.add(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed - it's immutable only in so far as someone with a reference to **only** the `ImmutableArray` object cannot add or remove items.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that it was storing the mutable Array.